# Texmaker doesn't find french babel

Tags: texmaker, babel, french

I've installed TexLive 2015 from tug.org.
When I try to compile my file using Texmaker including :

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

Texmaker returns :

```
! Package babel Error: Unknown option `francais'. Either you misspelled it
(babel) or the language definition file francais.ldf was not fou
nd.
```

Same problem with \usepackage[francais]{babel} but works with \usepackage[english]{babel}.

I don't have any probems with :

```
$ pdflatex myFile.tex
```

or using other software such as TeXwork.

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Something may have gone wrong during the process of installing the TeXLive2015 distribution. Or, do you maybe have an older version of TeXLive, or possibly an entirely different TeX distribution, on your system as well? (I have TeXLive2015 as well, and running `\usepackage[french]{babel}` causes no problems.)

Comment: Perhaps you compiled first with the (deprecated) `francais` option. Remove the auxiliary files before compiling again.

Comment: @Mico, did you get you TexLive distribution from https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html ( install-tl-unx.tar.gz ). If yes, I will try to re install the complete version without removing any packages.

Comment: @dagnic - I definitely installed the full version of TeXLive2015.

Comment: I solved the problem with re installing the complete distribution. Thanks !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because problem solved by reinstall

Comment: Yes It could be @samcarter. I need to do something?

Comment: If you want and agree click on the close button below the question. But you don't have to do this if you don't want.

Comment: I don't find that button